# I changed my user name in the registery and my user account doesn't work properly

Tags: regedit

I wanted change user profile name and was go to regedit in local-machine, microsoft, windows nt, currentVersion profile list and in ProfileImagePath change the name. But after this my user profile became working inccorect. It became as a new user that can't change anything because all data will delete. I go again in register but i can't change the username because folder Windows NT not exist

Answer (score 0):

Is it not trivial to change a Windows User Profile name. I suggest (very strongly) that you do not bother and leave it alone.

Too late in this case.

Make a Windows bootable USB Key, start with that and try recovering the data you need.

> It became as a new user that can't change anything because all data
> will deleted.

If true then the process I outline above may be your only hope.

If the new user is a member of Administrators, are you able to take ownership of the required data without losing it?

[Take ownership of folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/982991/cannot-take-ownership-to-folder)

When you have recovered your data, reinstall Windows and restore the data

Comment: In the future, after you recover data: to change user name, in **User Accounts** CPL, select **Change your account name**.